# How to change background of prefs activity?

Tags: java, android, android-preferences

I have a prefs xml activity with one checkbox for sound on and off and an editbox for user to type in his/her name. Is there a way to make the prefs activity fullscreen and to set a background? I want to set my own png background, if it's possible. Thanks.

Comment: Please confirm whether this answer worked for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Theme and set `android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"` in your `<activity>`
Create a `CustomTheme` in your styles.xml with following items

```
<style name="CustomTheme">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/backgroundimage</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did worked in some weird way. I did get my background but it's stretched 3 or 4 times the size of my screen, vertically. My checkbox is lost somewhere down. :)

Comment: Can you post your layout xml file?

Comment: If I am reading it correctly, the image you are using is stretched and displayed multiple times on the screen. The checkbox is not clearly visible though it is still there? If this is the case, you will have to create multiple images for different screen sizes and put them in different drawable folders . You may have to create new drawablw folders in the res folder based on the screen size you are using, for example, drawable-small, drawable-normal, etc. Please see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) link

Comment: See my edited response. Try `android:windowBackground` instead of `android:background`

Comment: I have this same background image in the rest of my game, and it works in every activity. Only this one is a problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundimage"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Here 'backgroundimage' is the image from your res.

In oncreate() -

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: No, I can't have linear layout in a preference xml.

Answer (score 0):

My pref.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<EditTextPreference
    android:title="Ime"
    android:key="ime"
    android:summary="Upišite svoje ime">
</EditTextPreference>

<CheckBoxPreference
    android:title="Zvuk"
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:key="checkbox"
    android:summary="Ukljucite ili iskljucite zvukove u igri"/>

</PreferenceScreen>
```